# Receiving 'Expected a component class, got [objectObject]' error in react-native ios app

Tags: react-native

I cannot workout why this error is appearing (I actually don't even know what it means!)  Normally the red screen errors point to a file location but this doesn't although it points to the use of 'new' so I assume the issue is this file, as it was working up to this point:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ListView } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PeopleItem from './PeopleItem';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 353,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 20,
  },
});

class PeopleList extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.people);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView 
          enableEmptySections={true}
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => 
            <PeopleItem people={rowData} />
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { people: state.people };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PeopleList);
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Apologies, this was not the file causing the error, I've resolved it - not quite sure how though!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I didn't capitilize a  element in the file being called - that just cost me about 3hrs.

Comment: Didn't help that it couldn't tell me which file!